# Differences between the way men and women interpret body language

Tags: social-psychology, communication, sex-differences, body-language

There are many socially accepted ideas about the differences between men and women, I am wondering how much of this is misconception or based in reality.

I was reading this question: [How important is eye contact for attraction between a man and woman?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/4450/how-important-is-eye-contact-for-attraction-between-a-man-and-woman) and found some interesting discussion in the comments.

I quote from [this answer](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/4453/3543):

> females are very good at picking up subtleties like that - however, they are very bad at explaining them usually.

I quote from one of the [comments](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/4450/how-important-is-eye-contact-for-attraction-between-a-man-and-woman#comment9066_4453):

> "Females . . . are very bad at explaining them usually"? That seems like an unnecessarily dangerous statement--humans in general are quite bad at pinpointing reasons for social behavior

I found this article:
Gender Affects Body Language Reading
Arseny A. Sokolov, et al doi: [10.3389/fpsyg.2011.00016](https://doi.org/10.3389/fpsyg.2011.00016)

> The findings show that gender affects accuracy rather than speed of body language reading. This effect, however, is modulated by emotional content of actions: males surpass in recognition accuracy of happy actions, whereas females tend to excel in recognition of hostile angry knocking. Advantage of women in recognition accuracy of neutral actions suggests that females are better tuned to the lack of emotional content in body actions. The study provides novel insights into understanding of gender effects in body language reading, and helps to shed light on gender vulnerability to neuropsychiatric and neurodevelopmental impairments in visual social cognition.

However, this is only one study, and it raises the interesting point that women may be better at interpreting "lack of emotional content".

**Has current research reached a consensus on the  differences between the way men and women interpret body language?

If so; What are the proposed reasons for these differences?**